# How can I quickly debug a SageMaker training script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

When running an ML training job in Amazon SageMaker, the training script is "deployed" and given an ML training instance, which takes about 10 minutes to spin up and get the data it needs.

I can only get one error message from the training job, then it dies and the instance is killed along with it.

After I make a change to the training script to fix it, I need to deploy and run it which takes another 10 minutes or so.

How can I accomplish this faster, or keep the training instance running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are running a training job using one of the SageMaker frameworks. Given that, you can use the "local mode" feature of SageMaker, which will run your training job (specifically the container) locally in your notebook instance. That way, you can iterate on your script until it works. Then you can move on to the remote training cluster to train the model against the whole dataset if needed. To use local mode, you just set the instance type to "local". More details about local mode can be found at https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk#sagemaker-python-sdk-overview and the blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-the-amazon-sagemaker-local-mode-to-train-on-your-notebook-instance/

Answer (score 2):

If you're using TF, MXNet, Pytorch or Chainer, local mode is indeed a much faster way to iterate. An even faster solution is to code and debug on your local machine with a toy dataset, making sure that your training/prediction code runs properly before moving it to SageMaker. You can even use the same containers as on SageMaker, as they're all open source, e.g. https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container.

If you're using a custom container, then you can work locally as well before pushing it to ECR and using it with SageMaker.

If you're using a built-in algo, there's no other option than training/predicting with SageMaker-managed instances. However, you're not writing the ML code in this case, so there's less risk of running into problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SageMaker now offers a way of debugging machine learning models using the new functionality called SageMaker Debugger. This functionality will allow you to capture the tensors flowing through the computational graph and analyze them in real time. Based on the result of the analysis happening in real time, you can choose to stop the training job and separately analyze the tensors in an interactive fashion to debug your model.

See: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/amazon_sagemaker_debugger.html